# VBA OPENROWSET syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: excel, vba, openrowset

I want to be able to JOIN Excel tables to MsSQL tables, or to other Excel tables. I am trying to test the second case. I'm  trying to get data from Excel table using the OPENROWSET. Later I will use this to join tables, but now I cant get working even this simple query.

`Ciselnik1` is a Worksheet in Test.xlsx Workbook and contains a small table with header:

```
FK__S_HEAD | Desc
-------------------------------
ODD AM     | ODD - description1
ODDZP      | ODD - desc2
```

The follwing code is throwing the "syntax error in FROM clause" error:

```
Sub TestExternalSQLwithCisJoin()
 Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection, objCmd As ADODB.Command, objRS As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim sPath As String, sSQL As String, sConn As String

 Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
 Set objCmd = New ADODB.Command
 Set objRS = New ADODB.Recordset

 sSQL = "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(""Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"",""Database=c:\...\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"",""SELECT * FROM [Ciselnik1$]"")"

 sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\...\Test.xlsm;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES"";"

 Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

 'MsgBox sSQL 

 objConn.Open sConn
 'objRS.Open sSQL, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
 objConn.Execute sSQL, lngRecsAff, adExecuteNoRecords

 Dim A0cell As Range
 Worksheets("Test").Activate
 Set A0cell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(1, 1)
 A0cell.CopyFromRecordset objRS

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OPENROWSET is just not a function the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider supports.